# Android Spinner Guidance

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to create an android drop down box but finding it difficult to find a suitable example that isn't overly complicated.

What I want is a simple drop down box with 4 or 5 options in it. Those options should be placed in an xml file that the spinner reads in.

All the examples have dealt with multiple spinners on a page of seem to have bloated code that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In res > Values > Strings

```
<string-array name="mySpinnerOptions">
    <item>Cow</item>
    <item>Dog</item>
    <item>Cat</item>
    <item>Horse</item>
</string-array>
```

In your content_myView file

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    android:entries="@array/mySpinnerOptions"
    android:layout_width="your_width"
    android:layout_height="your_height"/>
```

Comment: ah perfect - it really is that simple! I thought it must be but everything else had a load of code in the java files etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that you can get the gist of from steps 1 and 2.

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Summary:

1. Create string array in strings.xml
2. Add `android:entries="@array/your_array"` to your Spinner component in your layout xml